# Cannot response a pdf file in circus

Tags: pyramid, wkhtmltopdf, circusd

I have done to implement a print pdf function. I use **pyramid**, **wkhtmltopdf** and **jinja2** to generate pdf. It works fine in **gunicorn**. However, when I deploy it to production (I use **circusd** to run in production), the function fails without any error message. The source code is as follow:

```
pdf_renderer = PDFRenderer()

request = self.request

html = render('test.jinja2' , pdf_data, request)

response = request.response
response.write(pdf_renderer(html))
response.content_type = 'application/pdf'
response.headerlist.append(('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='test.pdf'))

#Everything is ok except the final statement.
#circusd cannot run the statement "return response"
#However, gunicorn can do it
return response
```

So, do you have any suggestion or idea about my problem? It's so straight and I cannot understand why it works fine in **gunicorn** but fails in **circusd**

Comment: By `circusd` do you mean chaussette, and if so, what backend? Circus is not a WSGI server and should have no effect on the types of responses that can be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `content_length`. It's possible the WSGI server you are using does not support streaming responses (which would happen if you are using `.write()` or `.app_iter` without setting a `content_length`). For your use-case, it's more likely that you'd be happy just setting the `body` which would take care of everything for you.

```
response.body = pdf_renderer(html)
```